# Replace HTML page with contents retrieved via AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I have an HTML page with a typical structure:

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="..." ></script>
   <style>...</style>
  </head>
  <body>
   content
  </body>
  <script>
    var success_callback = function(data) {
      // REPLACE PAGE CONTENT & STRUCTURE WITH "data"
    }
    ajax(url, params, success_callback);
  </script>
</html>
```

Do you think it is possible ?  I've already tried to give the html tag an id and doing `$(id).replace(data);` with no success.

Don't ask me why, but that is what I need (I'm working with a special "mashup builder" site... it is a long story).

**EDIT** : I forgot to say that **scripts in the received content have to be executed**, even external scripts included using `<script src="...">`.

Comment: I'd be really interested to find out more about the requirements. I can't think of anything that would require such a thing.

Comment: which js library are you using?  retag to include it.

Comment: It seems to work with normal JavaScript(I am using Chrome). 
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = 'Input HTML here';

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The simplest way is to set the new HTML content using:

```
document.open();
document.write(newContent);
document.close();
```

Comment: +1 because this answer replaces the entire document, not just contents of the body tag

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't work in Internet Explorer. Causes an 'Access Denied' error.

Comment: In Chrome Version 39.0.2171.65 m, this merely appends to the document.

Comment: Please notice that this method works exactly as requested, but it does not update browser history. If you click back button in your browser after "document.write()" action, you won't go back to the page before redirect, you will go to the one before it.

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer. Upvote from me, it is :)

Comment: @IgnacioSegura: you can always use the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/History).

Comment: Should this always trigger dom loaded event afterwards?

Comment: @niutech, .close is optional

Comment: To anyone viewing this in 2019+, this works for me in the latest versions of Chrome and IE

Comment: I personally use this as this also executes JavaScript, unlike the innerHTML method

Comment: This causes flickering and Firefox's MDN advises against it

Answer (score 28):

try this with **jQuery**:

```
$('body').load( url,[data],[callback] );
```

Read more at [docs.jquery.com / Ajax / load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback)

Answer (score 12):

Here's how to do it in [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/api/element/update): `$(id).update(data)`

And [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/replaceWith#content): `$('#id').replaceWith(data)`

But `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=data` should work too.

EDIT: Prototype and jQuery automatically evaluate scripts for you.

Comment: this causes screen flickering (eg. if you have a black background)

Answer (score 6):

You could try doing

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ajax_response
```

Answer (score 6):

the simplest way is

```
$("body").html(data);
```

Comment: It requires jQuery first. It's not good option, if you need it done immidately, without loading external libs.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just try to replace the body content with the document.body handler?

if your page is this:

```
<html>
<body>
blablabla
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.innerHTML="hi!";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just use the document.body to replace the body.

This works for me. All the content of the BODY tag is replaced by the innerHTML you specify.
If you need to even change the html tag and all childs you should check out which tags of the 'document.' are capable of doing so.

An example with javascript scripting inside it:

```
<html>
<body>
blablabla
<script type="text/javascript">
var changeme = "<button onClick=\"document.bgColor = \'#000000\'\">click</button>";
document.body.innerHTML=changeme;
</script>
</body>
```

This way you can do javascript scripting inside the new content. Don't forget to escape all double and single quotes though, or it won't work. escaping in javascript can be done by traversing your code and putting a backslash in front of all singe and double quotes.

Bare in mind that server side scripting like php doesn't work this way. Since PHP is server-side scripting it has to be processed before a page is loaded. Javascript is a language which works on client-side and thus can not activate the re-processing of php code.

Comment: Yes, you are almost right, but external scripts included using a <script src="..."> are not executed.

Comment: You could traverse the code and make it load those files (and execute them) dynamically as done here: http://www.codehouse.com/javascript/articles/external/
This way all the script found can be added dynamically... or is this too much?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are using jQuery or something similar. If you are using jQuery, then the following should work:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
   content
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("body").load(url);
</script>
</html>
```