# Simple: replace div with ajax content (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483745/replace-html-page-with-contents-retrieved-via-ajax). I now have:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#gc').load('test');">reload</a>... </span>
<div id="gc">
    empty
</div>
```

This is what I am getting:

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert '$('#gc')' to object
Error thrown at line 1, column 0 in <anonymous function>(event):
    $('#gc').load('test');
```

What is that? I thought I would be able to select a div and replace the contents with load()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try attaching the event handler on `domready`:

HTML:

```
<a href="some-url" class="reload_link">reload</a>
...
```

JS:

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
     $('.reload_link').click(function() {
        $(this).next('div').load(this.href);
        return false;
     });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I like to wrap my `jQuery` code inside of an anonymous function using a `$` argument to avoid name conflicts with other libraries. (Of course, I could just use `jQuery.noConflict()` as well)

The way this works is it retrieves all elements in the document that have a class of `reload_link`, then for each one, it retrieves the next `<div>` element and invokes `load`, passing in the current `<a>` element's `href` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can I easily mark more <a>-elements with reload_link? And can you shortly explain WHY this works?

Comment: @user469110 You can use a `class` and select on those, maybe even utilize the `href` attribute to determine which URL gets loaded...

Comment: Why it works? Because Jquery gets ready when the page is fully loaded. Because "onclicks" get registered before jquery is ready, it cant work.