# Do I sent two requests to the ActionResult?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, get

I have an ASP.net MVC project and depending on the filter options chosen by the user I am sending different ajax requests to the same actionresult, for example:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#filter_reset_button", function () {
    var url = "/Admin/Index";

    ajaxRequest({
        url: url,
        type: "get",
        data: { reset: true },
        successCallback: function () {
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    });
});
```

Other listeners sent different data, something like:

```
 data: { page: 2, filterUpdate: true }
```

and so on. The Index ActionResult returns different lists of items, depending on different options chosen in the data and the code works completely fine.

A colleage of mine told me, that my code is actually sending two get requests to the AR everytime, so its not efficient. Is that true? And if its the case, how can I refactor it. to make it just one request? If I let window.location.href = url part out, the site actually doesnt load the server response.

Comment: Add the sample of Index Action method so others may help you further.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct 2 request called.

First request when you call `AJAX get` to Action Index in Admin Controller.

Second request when you set  `window.location.href = url`, it will same as you enter `/Admin/Index` in browser.

In this case you only need `window.location.href = '/admin/index?reset=true'` in click function

Comment: So is there a way to improve my code? Because without the window.location.href my browser  doesn`t load the server response into the window.

Comment: you dont need ajax in this case, you can only use /admin/index?reset=true

Comment: It sadly wouldn`t work, we have some complex logic in the Index AR and reset is one of many parameters, so basically if I do  /admin/index?reset=true it deletes another options which were already saved, but if I do Ajax request and windows.location.href after that, reset gets saved into the AR and the new page loads with all the previously saved options (reset = true included).

Comment: You need return data in result ajax and update UI base on json data

Comment: Could you explain it a little bit more in depth? I am not sure I understand how to do  what you have written there.

Comment: In index action, you need check Request.IsAjaxRequest, if yes you need return Json( Data = { your data } ), in success function of ajax, you iterate data and display in UI by jquery

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are doing 2 request in button click. First in `Ajax` Get, Second in Success Call Back.

But Why are you calling `window.location.href = url;` `success` call back. ?

If you want update the page after click, you can do partial updates to page. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146212/can-you-just-update-a-partial-view-instead-of-full-page-post) post.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the post here [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914245/how-to-replace-the-entire-html-webpage-with-ajax-response)

Actually on success callback you must change your code accordingly to the above post